# How to Include HPP and CPP File in ROS2 Package

Tags: c++, ros2

I am currently working on a ROS2 Package where I have a CPP File that uses a HPP File (there is a CPP File to this HPP File) in it. All the Files are in the src Folder of the Package. As long as I don't include those files I can use colcon build as usual and execute the program, but as soon as I include the HPP File I get the error "undefined reference to 'namspace I include'".
I think that I will have to create some kind of dependency in the CMakeList.txt but I couldn't find a solution online.
I hope that someone has an idea on how I can fix this problem.

Here is the CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(rover2-1_ros)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
  find_package(std_msgs REQUIRED)
  find_package(sensor_msgs REQUIRED)
  add_executable(gamepad src/joystick_rover_control.cpp)
  add_executable(i2c_driver src/I2C_driver.cpp)
  ament_target_dependencies(gamepad rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs)
  ament_target_dependencies(i2c_driver rclcpp std_msgs sensor_msgs)

  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()


install(DIRECTORY launch
 DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
)

install(TARGETS
  gamepad
  i2c_driver
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})


ament_package()
```

The File that I am talking about is the I2C_driver.cpp and I want to include a File called SerialPort.hpp (and therefore the SerialPort.cpp that belongs to it), which is in the same folder.
I am including the file like this:

```
#include "SerialPort.hpp"
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer myself. I had to use #include "SerialPort.cpp" too, not only the hpp file, like usual

Comment: Hi, I am having same issue. Did you figure out how not to #include xxx.cpp?